# FlutterFlowRadioButton Text value option and get ID

Tags: radio-button, flutterflow

I'm new to flutterflow. I made supabase tables for my association.

A "membership" table which contains the formulas that we offer to our members.

A "family" table with the surnames of our members and the membership ID.

On one page, I have a radio button that displays the list of members' names. A text field for entering the surname and a button for saving.

As the radio button doesn't display the ID but the membership name, I don't know how to record the ID in the "Family" table. Conversely, when I edit a family, I'll need to be able to select the right radio button from the ID.

Can you help me?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. As far as I can tell its not possible with the radio select which is baffling and defeats the purpose of this widget. If you found a solution I'd be curious to hear it.